# Convert string arrays to numbers

Tags: python

I have an `array = ["3", "5", "3", "", "1"]`. How to convert to numbers everything except "" must be None in python in one line?

I tried something like this: `[float(num) for num in array if num != ""]` but that skipped "".

Comment: `[float(num) if num!="" else None for num in array]`

Comment: Oh, I am dumb, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what to the right of the `for` statement in a list comprehension is a *filter* expression.

You want to issue a value no matter what, so you don't want a filter, you want a *ternary expression*:

```
[float(num) if num else None for num in array]
```

(you can omit `num != ""` since `num` is a string, not a float or integer, so it's equivalent and shorter)

which results in:

```
[3.0, 5.0, 3.0, None, 1.0]
```

Comment: Also can simply be `if num` without strictly checking for empty string.

Comment: @CasualDemon well, yes, since inputs are not strings. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Simple List Comprehension:

```
num_list = [float(e) if e else None for e in map(lambda x: x.strip(), array)]
```

Before converting we strip the strings so no leading or trailing spaces.

This will map " " to "", which can be then checked using `if`.

Comment: Not the DVer, but it doesn't replace the empty string with `None` like the OP requested

Comment: @Wondercricket Edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
array = ["3", "5", "3", "", "1"]

final_list = [int(i) if i else None for i in array]
```

Output:

```
[3, 5, 3, None, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if you want `""` to equal `None` or not.

If you want to just drop `""` then:

```
array = ["3", "5", "3", "", "1"]
print [float(x) for x in array if x]
// result: [3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 1.0]
```

If you want to replace `""` with `None`:

```
array = ["3", "5", "3", "", "1"]
print [float(x) if x else None for x in array]
// result: [3.0, 5.0, 3.0, None, 1.0]
```